# How does Jackson automatically deserialize java.nio.file.Path?

Tags: java, json, jackson, java.nio.file

I'm not complaining, but would like to understand why it works.

This is my Java class:

```
public static class ExampleClass {
  private Path target;

  public Path getTarget() {
    return target;
  }

  public void setTarget(Path target) {
    this.target = target;
  }
}
```

And this is the JSON:

```
{
  "target": "some/path"
}
```

Now a simple test shows that it works:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ExampleClass exampleClass = mapper.readValue(json, ExampleClass.class);
assertEquals(Path.of("some/path"), exampleClass.getTarget());
```

But how? There is no (public) constructor in `Path`, that accepts a `String`. How does Jackson know that it needs to call `Path.of()`?

Comment: it uses reflection to set the field and probably [`PathDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ext/PathDeserializer.html)

Comment: OK, so it has a number of predefined deserializers, not just for standard `java.lang` and `java.util`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jackson's `ObjectMapper` comes with predefined standard serializers/deserializers out of the box. For Jackson version `2.10.1` there is [`NioPathDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ext/NioPathDeserializer.html) (since version `2.8`) which will be called when deserialazing to `Path` objects.

Comment: Is there any register, that enumerates the predefined deserializers (except the Direct Known Subclasses of [StdScalarDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdScalarDeserializer.html)) and is there any methodology behind why which deserializer has been implemented?